# how to send multiple values in href URL in php

Tags: php, url, href

```
<a href="userrequest.php?id=15">
```

i want to send the datas are id=15&name=svt in same url.Thanks in Advance

Comment: And what exactly is your issue? Can you please state that first?

Comment: `<a href="userrequest.php?id=15&name=svt">` Did you try it?

Comment: @mkaatman if we want to be correct for such a stupid question, then please `<a href="userrequest.php?id=15&amp;name=svt">`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do what yourself said:

```
<a href="userrequest.php?id=15&name=svt">
```

**Edit #1**:

as @Rob said, it is standard to use `&amp;` instead of `&`. Then use:

```
<a href="userrequest.php?id=15&amp;name=svt">
```

Comment: should be &amp; instead of &

Comment: @RobGudgeon No, there's no need to use &amp; instead of &. What's your reason?

Comment: Read the replies at http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?519947-Do-I-use-quot-amp-amp-quot-instead-of-just-quot-amp-quot-character-in-a-URL-string - also try running any HTML that just uses & through the W3C Validator (http://validator.w3.org/), it will fail to validate.

Comment: @RobGudgeon Yes, your'e right. Thanks for that.